# is $[0,1]^\omega$ with product topology a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$

Tags: general-topology

Is $[0,1]^\omega$ with product topology a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ denote the space of countably many products of $\mathbb{R}$. Is the subspace locally compact?

Comment: What does $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ have to do with anything? Being compact/locally compact is an intrinsic property of a space. It doesn't matter where it's embedded.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Hi.  Why is it not valid ? I remember in Munkres topology the following defintion was stated: Let $X$ be a topological space $A\subseteq X$ is said to be a compact subspace of $X$ iff for every set of open subsets of $X$ that cover $A$ have a finite subset of open sets that cover $A$

Comment: @Chris Eagle Thus I think the terminology is OK. Am I right ?

Comment: @StefanH.: $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not locally compact.

Comment: @NateEldredge: You are right, thank you! I was too over-hasty and didn't think this through. But it it true for finite products.

Comment: @NateEldredge: why $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not locally compact? can you explain how to prove it? thank you.

Comment: This is Tychonoff's theorem. An arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact with the product topology. Also a finite product of locally compact spaces is locally compact.

Comment: @StefanH.: Yeah. Thx. But why is $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ not locally compact? It apparently doesn't fall into any of the two situations you mentioned.

Comment: @Alex: In $\mathbb R^\omega$ there is no compact set containing an open set. A basic open set is of the form $\prod_{n>0}U_n$, where the $U_n$ are open and only finitely many of them are proper subsets from $\Bbb R$. But a set containing such a set is not compact.

Comment: @StefanH.: Okay, I see. It surely is not locally compact. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Tychonoff's theorem, the product of any family of compact spaces is compact, so $[0,1]^\omega$ is compact. Compactness is a property that a space possesses or not, independent of the surrounding space, so it is a compact subspace of $\Bbb R^\omega$, given that the product topology on $[0,1]^\omega$ is the same as the topology as a subspace. That seems like a trivial fact, and a proof that a product of subspaces is a subspace of the product is indeed easy, using the universal property of the initial topology.

$[0,1]^\omega$ is also locally compact, as is every product of compact locally compact spaces. Here *locally compact* means that every point has a local base of compacts sets.

Comment: Note that if you work with the definition "locally compact iff every point has a compact neighbourhood", then compact trivially implies locally compact, so the last statement doesn't have much content in that case.

Comment: That's right. I will include the definition in my answer.

Comment: Not every product of locally compact spaces is locally compact. The product $X$ of locally compact spaces $X_i$ is locally compact iff all but finitely many of them are compact (which is the case here, as all are compact).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: That's why I wrote "compact locally compact spaces".